# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensoflow'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

```
%matplotlib inline

import tensoflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from rnn.lstm_recurrent_model import LSTMRecurrentModel
from rnn.lstm_solver import LSTMSolver
from rnn.data_util import load_word_based_text_input
```

**But I got error like below**

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      2 
----> 3 import tensoflow as tf
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensoflow'

Tensoflow version : 1.15
Keras version : 2.2.0

Comment: It's a typo. Should be `tensorflow`

Comment: Now I am getting this.       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rnn.lstm_recurrent_model'                 But I have installed pip install rnn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

You have mistakenly written

```
import tensoflow as tf
```

Typing mistake.